# Problem with table using \multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm getting some little problems when using `\multirow`:

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |l| c| c| } \hline
  \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} \\ \hline
  \multirow{4}{*}{A} & 1 & 1 \\
   & 2 & 2 \\
   & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
   \multirow{4}{*}{B}  & 1 & 1 \\
      & 2 & 2 \\
     \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Here is the preview:

[image]

Problems:

1. As you can see, in cell (2,1), the B is not properly positioned in the middle of the cell
2. How is it possible to separate only multirows in Row 1?

Comment: The first argument to `\multirow` is the number of rows spanned: it should be 3 in the first case, 2 in the second case. The second question is not clear.

Comment: I just want an \hline between all rows in Column 2 and 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want an output like this:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|} \hline
  \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} \\ \hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{A} & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{2-3}
   & 2 & 2 \\ \cline{2-3}
   & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{B} & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{2-3}
  & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

1. Use the right number of rows when using `\multirow`.
2. Use `\cline{<start column>-<end column>}` to get partial horizontal lines.